# Xamarin animation ViewAnimations not working

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my xamarin.forms app. I have a ViewExtension of Animations to use across my app. It is like this.

```
public static class ViewAnimations
    {
        public static async Task FadeAnimY(View view)
        {
            await Task.WhenAll
             (
                  view.FadeTo(1, 400),
                  view.TranslateTo(0, 0, 400)
             );
        }
        public static async Task ClickEffect(View view)
        {
            await Task.WhenAll
             (
                  view.ScaleTo(1.2, 100),
                  view.ScaleTo(1, 100)
             );
        }

    }
```

When I call this method for a label tap gesture like this,

```
     private async void Checkin_label_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
              await ViewAnimations.ClickEffect(checkinlabel);
                   
        }
```

Nothing happens. But when I call it like

```
  private async void Checkin_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {         
             await checkinIcon.ScaleTo(1.2, 100);
             await checkinIcon.ScaleTo(1, 100);
        }
```

It simply works. Why former method not working? What I am missing? Any help is appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `Task.WhenAll` doesn't do the tasks defined within it in any particular order or even synchronously. It should be used when you just want the tasks to be completed but not in any particular order.

**Scenario 1**

```
await Task.WhenAll
(
    Task1.Run(),
    Task2.Run()
);
//Task3 or method calls or some logic;
```

When you want your task 1 and 2 to be completed before the compiler moves ahead you should put it in WhenAll.

But if you want your tasks to be done in a particular order like in this animation case, they shouldn't be wrapped inside `WhenAll` as this may be done in **any particular order** or **even concurrently** as suited by the thread.

You can checkout [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-is-the-difference-between-task-whenall-and-task-waitall-in-chash) the working of `Task.WhenAll`

Comment: Hi thanks for helping me. So should I dont use Task.WhenAll in this case?

Comment: No, because you want it to be done synchronously. First, you want to scale up and then scale down. You can use `WhenAll` in this method `FadeAnimY` as the order doesn't matter here. Maybe UX will be compromised but the end result will be the same. But in this case. It can scale down first or scale after or do it concurrently defeating the purpose.